# Google Maps not centering after dynamically loading latitude/longitude on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm dynamically loading latitude/longitude variables and passing them to the Google Maps `Initialize();` function.

```
function initialize() {
    var lat = $('.map_img', '.inview').attr('data-lat');
    var lng = $('.map_img', '.inview').attr('data-lng');
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 15,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
}
```

So I'm pulling these coordinates via the `data` attribute, which is set via a wordpress widget and giving them to Google Maps.

I want to run the function, getting new coordinates every time the user clicks these left/right buttons.

```
<a href="#" class="btn-prev">previous</a>

<a href="#" class="btn-next">next</a>

$('.btn-prev').click(function () {
    //initialize maps script again
    initialize();
});

$('.btn-next').click(function () {
    //initialize maps script again
    initialize();
});
```

Then the user clicks on a Map image which opens the large map with the new coordinates.

```
var mapImg = $('.map_img');
var $overlay = $('.overlay'),
    resize = true,
    map;
mapImg.click(function () {
    $overlay.show();
    if (resize) {
        initialize();
        resize = false;
    }
});
```

The problem I'm having is that after the first click the Map is not centered. I had assumed `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');` would solve this problem.

I'm not sure why this is happening so I've created a fiddle to replicate the issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/3CXSs/13/

Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "click", function () {
    var center = map.getCenter();
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
    map.setCenter(center);
});
```

Not efficient code because I'm not excatly sure how it fits into your code, but it will recenter the map every time someone clicks somewhere. It should give you some idea of the code you need, if you have any trouble let me know.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63PXa/1/) (you also seem to have a bug where it doesn't change the map on the first next/prev click.

Comment: Ah, fantastic, I was literally playing around with getCenter but it wasn't working out. Yea, I didn't notice that bug because I was only seeing a little piece of the map, but this is progress :)

Comment: p.p.s fixed that big, I jsut triggered my function a little later int he button click.